# How do I get PyCharm to recognize a library?

Tags: pycharm

I have the following reference in one of my code files.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
```

The code runs well on my server, but PyCharm does not recognize rest_framework so puts red squiggy lines under both rest_framework and serializers.

How do I get PyCharm to recognize the rest_framework library?

Comment: Are you sure your interpreter has this library installed?

Comment: No, I didn't know I needed to do that. I belive that your comment is basically an answer to my question.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I go to settings>Project>Project interpreter. There I click on + and get a popup called availible packages. There I see tons of different rest intepreter but none for exactly django-rest-framework och rest-framework. How do I know which interpreter I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to put the cursor on the line with error and press 
**alt+enter** and choose Install package. PyCharm will automatically install the package and after some time it will index it.